# C#/LINQ & Infamous ORA-00933: SQL Command not properly ended

Tags: c#, oracle, linq

I have the following C#/LINQ statement (using Visual Studio 2010) that gives me the above error:

```
var cityResults = TaxRates
    .Where(a => a.TaxType.Equals("CI"))
    .OrderBy(a => a.Description).ThenByDescending(a => a.CreateDate)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Description)
    .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault());
```

I simply want the query to bring back all the columns from the TaxRates table, grouped by DESCRIPTION and bring back the most recent CREATEDATE row.

Running Oracle 9i.

For what's it's worth, the following works just fine and brings back exactly what I want:

```
var cityResults = TaxRates
    .Where(x => x.TaxType.Equals("CI"))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Description)
    .Select(x => x.First());
```

However, this is because I'm using the below data structure instead of going against a database/table:

```
public static List<MyCities> TaxRates = new List<MyCities>
{
new MyCities {Description = "Boston",    TaxType = "CI", CreateDate = 120, TaxAmt = 5.7},
new MyCities {Description = "Houston",   TaxType = "CI", CreateDate = 116, TaxAmt = 5.7},
new MyCities {Description = "Boston",    TaxType = "CI", CreateDate = 121, TaxAmt = 5.6},
new MyCities {Description = "Las Vegas", TaxType = "CI", CreateDate = 114, TaxAmt = 5.7},
new MyCities {Description = "Boston",    TaxType = "CI", CreateDate = 115, TaxAmt = 5.9},
new MyCities {Description = "Phoenix",   TaxType = "CI", CreateDate = 118, TaxAmt = 5.7},
new MyCities {Description = "Colorado",  TaxType = "ST", CreateDate = 113, TaxAmt = 5.7},
new MyCities {Description = "Seattle",   TaxType = "CI", CreateDate = 112, TaxAmt = 5.7},
new MyCities {Description = "Orlando",   TaxType = "CI", CreateDate = 111, TaxAmt = 5.7},
new MyCities {Description = "Miami",     TaxType = "CI", CreateDate = 119, TaxAmt = 5.7},
new MyCities {Description = "Boston",    TaxType = "CO", CreateDate = 122, TaxAmt = 5.7},
new MyCities {Description = "Eugene",    TaxType = "CI", CreateDate = 121, TaxAmt = 5.7}
};

public class MyCities
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string TaxType { get; set; }
    public int CreateDate { get; set; }
    public double TaxAmt { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the following works?

`var cityResults = TaxRates
    .Where(a => a.TaxType.Equals("CI"))
    .OrderBy(a => a.Description).ThenByDescending(a => a.CreateDate)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Description)
    .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault());
    .ToList()
    .Dump();`

Comment: Your solution without the .ToList() works great in LinqPad.  However, adding the .ToList() in C# causes a LinqCommandExecuteionExcetion with the same error message as the title of this question.  Of course I removed the first semicolon.